# Why can't I make this object declaration in my class?

Tags: c++, class, object

When I do this, my compiler complains. There are 3 errors that emerge, though no error messages visible:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "ParseException.h"
#include "CycleFoundException.h"
#include "UnknownTargetException.h"

using namespace std;

class Maker
{
 private:
 vector<Node> storage;

 public:
 Maker(string file) throw (ParseException, CycleFoundException, UnknownTargetException);
 vector<string> makeTarget(string targetName);      
};

struct Node
{
    string target;
    vector<string> dependencies;
    string command;
    int discoverytime;
    int finishtime;
    int visited;
    Node* next;
};
```

The compiler does not like my `vector<Node> storage` declaration. When I do `vector<int> storage` instead, it compiles without complaint. Is it wrong to declare an object of one class in another class? I thought this was alright.

Comment: above `class Maker` add `class Node;` This is called forward declaration.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you need to put the definition of `Node` before the definition of `Maker`.

You use the type name `Node` in the definition of `Maker` (in the line `vector<Node> storage`), but because you haven't defined `Node` yet the compiler doesn't know what it is.

Comment: Would rearranging the order of the classes fix the issue then?

Comment: It should. Give it a try and see if it compiles.